# How to make default (resettable) int in python

Tags: python

I'd like to have an ability to reset an integer/float to the predefined default value without overriding all arithmetic operations. Something like

```
class DefaultInt(int):

def __init__(self, value):
    super(DefaultInt, self).__init__(value)
    self.default_value = value

def reset(self):
    self.value = self.default_value

my_int = DefaultInt(19)
my_int += 1
my_int.reset()
```

But there are two problems:

- I cannot access the hidden `value` itself by subclassing int class.
- After `my_int += 1` the `my_int` becomes, obviously, a simple int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your immediate problems:**

in-place addition needs you to redefine `__iadd__` (in-place addition) to return a `DefaultInt` object (better save the default value, else it becomes the new value)

The `reset` thing looks not possible as you've written, just because integers are immutable. But you could assign back the result of `reset` to the same name. That would work.

```
class DefaultInt(int):

    def __init__(self,value=0):
        super(DefaultInt, self).__init__()
        self.default_value = value

    def __iadd__(self,value):
        old_default = self.default_value
        r = DefaultInt(value + self)
        r.default_value = old_default
        return r

    def reset(self):
        return DefaultInt(self.default_value)

my_int = DefaultInt(19)
my_int += 1
print(my_int)
my_int = my_int.reset()
print(my_int)
```

output:

```
20
19
```

**Your long-term problems:**

But that's a first step. If you try `my_int + 12` you'll see that it returns an `int` as well: you'll have to define `__add__`. Same goes for `__sub__`... and there's the "hidden" value problem, and the immutable problem which prevents you to perform an in-place `reset`.

**Conclusion:**

I think the best approach would be *not to inherit* `int` and create your own, mutable, class with all the special methods crafted for your needs (plus the `reset` method that would work now). You won't have the constraints you're having when overriding `int`, and your code will be clearer, even if method-exhaustive (at least if a method is missing, you'll notice it, instead of calling a method that doesn't fit).

Answer (score -1):

I think that, if you only need a reset function, you can simply use:

```
default_value = 5
my_int = int.__new__(int, default_value)
my_int += 1
print my_int   #  prints 6
my_int = int.__new__(int, default_value)
print my_int   # prints 5
```